# Can free rebol 2.7.7 read in Windows Registry?

Tags: registry, rebol

I thought I have seen this somewhere but can't find it any more on google ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **No**: Free versions of REBOL do not include [Windows Registry functions](http://www.rebol.com/docs/sdk/registry.html).

Slightly longer answer: **Maybe with third-party add-on**: this [Mailing list thread](http://www.rebol.org/ml-display-thread.r?m=rmlBJVS) describes the use of **regtool.exe** using REBOL's **call** function.

*I've not tried it. Let us know if it works!*

Answer (score 1):

You need the Rebol SDK to access the 32 bit registry.